# Como se declara (mapea) un SQL_VARIANT en un Model - C# [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, model

Buenas es que tengo una tabla en SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Parametros(
    Empid       int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_Parametros_Empid] REFERENCES Empresa(id),
    Codigo      varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Valor       sql_variant NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parametros] PRIMARY KEY (Empid,Codigo))
```

Y pues tengo que crear el modelo de esa tabla para trabajar, y no se como declaro la columna 'valor' en el modelo.

Gracias

Comment: Y `sql_variant` que tipo de dato almacena?

Comment: cualquier tipo de dato, pues encontre de momento esta tabla de conversiones, la voy a probar

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: A lo que voy es que deseas guardar en esa columna que data planeas almacenar?

Comment: Son los parametros del programa, aveces sera un booleano (como activar o desactivar un parametro), otras una cadena (Como el Nit de la empresa o un codigo de facturacion, o resolucion de Camara de Comercio), en otras un numero (como el Iva que se va autilizar para las facturaciones) y asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontre la solucion, en el modelo tenia que agregarle `[Column(TypeName = "sql_variant")]` al campo SQL_Variant en la Base de datos para poderla mapear, en mi caso la columna se llama `Valor`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Parametro : Entidad
{
    public override string ToString() { return Codigo; }

    [Key]
    public int Empid { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "sql_variant")]
    public object Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No recomiendo uses este tipo de datos, no al menos si vas a usarlo en aplicaciones porque esta claro que no sabras que tipo de datos se persiste

Sino vas a tener retornar junto con el valor de que tipo de dato se persistio, para eso se usa `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`

[sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Como veras devolverias

```
SELECT Empid, 
       Codigo,
       Valor, 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Valor,'BaseType') AS 'DataType'
FROM Parametros
```

al tener el tipo de dato vas a tener que aplicar logica para saber a que tipo concreto castear en .net
Teniendo el tipo de datos se podria ver de hacer un conversor generico

[Convert or TryParse from string to T (generic) possible? work around?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3a139b0-9c14-400d-94f9-440b64a0122a/convert-or-tryparse-from-string-to-t-generic-possible-work-around?forum=csharplanguage)

```
public static T TryParse<T>(string inValue)
{
    TypeConverter converter =
        TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

    return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(null,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, inValue);
}
```

pero hay que ver como es que piensas usar el dato en la aplicacion, quizas usar un string para todos los tipos de datos sea mas simple

Comment: si se que es mas complicado trabajar con el, pero hace parte de los requerimientos del programa

Comment: entiendo, entonces vas a tener que retornar el tipo de dato que se persiste para poder castear en c#, sino la otra es que todo lo trabajes como string, no importa si es int, varchar, decimal, en codigo net puede ser todo string, digo si solo vas a mostrar el dato